# python : JSON string to dictionary

Tags: python, json

I need to parse a json string to extract the corresponding dictionary, but **I can't use json/ast modules or any other python module**. In more detail I have to load the .json file like that : `with open('test.json', 'rb') as file: myfile = file.read()` and then on this bytes I need to extract a dictionary. An example of the .json is

```
{"uploadAppName": "APP",
 "spawnAppType": "B",
 "deploy": 300,
 "bit": 0,
 "timeout_first_byte": 2,
 "timeout_spawn": 0,
 "timeout_task": 0,
 "task0": {
                "task_id": 0,
                "channel": 0
                }
}
```

To decode bytes I have to use `myfile = str(myfile, 'ascii')`, but starting from the string representation of the .json file I'm not able to extract a dictionary.

Comment: why can't you use dedicated module `json` ? First to avoid having bytes, just read in `"r"` mode not `"rb"`

Comment: just go to `json.py` somewhere in `site-packages` and copy-paste their code to your file... alternatively you could just use `my_dict = eval(myfile)`

Comment: I can't use eval too. I'm working on a subset of python for embedded devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved, this is my solution:

```
def read_json(filename):
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    json = str(f.read(), 'ascii').replace('\n', '').replace('\t', '').replace('}', '').replace('{', '')
y = json.split(',')
z = dict()
i = 0
dic = False
task_Key = 0
for elem in y:
    if elem.count(':') < 2 and not dic:
        q = elem.replace('"', '').split(':')
        if q[1].strip().isnumeric():
            z[q[0].strip()] = int(q[1].strip())
        elif '.' in q[1].strip():
            z[q[0].strip()] = float(q[1].strip())
        else:
            z[q[0].strip()] = q[1].strip()
    elif elem.count(':') == 2:
        i += 1
        dic = True

        q = elem.replace('"', '').split(':')
        task_Key = q[0].strip()
        z[q[0]] = dict()
        if q[2].strip().isnumeric():
            z[task_Key][q[1].strip()] = int(q[2].strip())
        elif '.' in q[2].strip():
            z[task_Key][q[1].strip()] = float(q[2].strip())
        else:
            z[task_Key][q[1].strip()] = q[2].strip()
    elif elem.count(':') < 2 and dic and i < 12:
        q = elem.replace('"', '').split(':')
        if q[1].strip().isnumeric():
            z[task_Key][q[0].strip()] = int(q[1].strip())
        elif '.' in q[1].strip():
            z[task_Key][q[0].strip()] = float(q[1].strip())
        else:
            z[task_Key][q[0].strip()] = q[1].strip()
        i += 1
    elif elem.count(':') < 2 and dic and i == 12:
        q = elem.replace('"', '').split(':')
        if q[1].strip().isnumeric():
            z[task_Key][q[0].strip()] = int(q[1].strip())
        elif '.' in q[1].strip():
            z[task_Key][q[0].strip()] = float(q[1].strip())
        else:
            z[task_Key][q[0].strip()] = q[1].strip()
        i = 0
        dic = False
return z
```

Answer (score -1):

If you can use the `exec` function, you could try this approach (although it's not the best practices):

```py
json_str = """{"uploadAppName": "APP",
 "spawnAppType": "B",
 "deploy": 300,
 "bit": 0,
 "timeout_first_byte": 2,
 "timeout_spawn": 0,
 "timeout_task": 0,
 "task0": {
                "task_id": 0,
                "channel": 0
                }
}"""

exec("data_dict = " + json_str)

# now you can access the data 
print(data_dict["deploy"])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I can't use exec too. I think the only solution can be the usage of str methods but I can't figure it out.